# In Apereo cas, is there a table shows that which version of cas-client supports which version of cas-server

Tags: java, cas

I am using Apereo CAS Server 4.1.x to build my SSO server with java, but I don't know which version of cas client is correct.
Is there a table shows that which version of cas client supports which version of cas server? like this:

```
cas-client cas-server
3.3.0      4.0.0 and later
3.2.1      3.0.0 and later
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All CAS clients should support all versions of the CAS server. Protocol compatibility is guaranteed.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this?